# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at <anonymous>:10:4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, console

[image: I am running this piece of code to see the response from api but it is throwing Ajax not a function error]

PS: I am using dummy url for posting on public platform perspective

```js
var plan;
var settings = {
  "url": "https://benefits-pas-stage.abc.com/PlanAvailability/web/facilities/100/plans/medical",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "UGxhbkF2YWlsYWJpbGl0eVRvb2wyMDE3MDI="
  },
};
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   plan = response;
console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I would assume you're using jQuery.slim, not the full jQuery library. The former is a lightweight version which does not include AJAX functionality (amongst other features). Use the full library instead.

Comment: I am checking it on console, where do i need to update the library in that case?

Comment: Find your `<script src="...jquery.slim.js` or similar and remove the `slim` part